# Secondary Name Node in Hadoop

Tags: namenode, hadoop3

Suppose for checkpoint default time is 1hr.
If Name Node goes down after 55min from last checkpoint.
We loss the last 55 min data(edit log file data is not added in fsImage)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Checkpoint node configuration parameters for **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns**

- **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period** : The number of seconds between two periodic checkpoints.
- **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns** : this will create a checkpoint of the namespace every ‘dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns’ transactions, regardless of whether ‘dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period’ has expired.

suposed you have your **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.period** every 1h and the **dfs.namenode.checkpoint.txns** every 500 transactions , the next checkpoint could be create in one hour or each 500 transactions